# How set default value as first value in angular select option

Tags: angularjs, dropdown, html-select

when am using this code.selected value shown as empty.i want select 1st value as one.

```
  <select class="form-control" name="cityID" id="Select1" ng-change="RoomSelect()" ng-model="sRoom">
                                            <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
                                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                                        </select>
```

When am using ng-model at the time default value selected as empty.otherwise its ok.

Comment: try init `sRoom` model in controller

Comment: try setting `sRoom=1` in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Try init `sRoom` model in controller

```
 $scope.sRoom = 1;
```

also its better use `ng-options` instead of repeat `option` in `select` tag.

***Demo***

```js
var app = angular.module('anApp', []);
app.controller('aCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sRoom = 1;
  
  $scope.chooses = [{"key":"one","value":1},{"key":"Two","value":2},{"key":"Three","value":3}];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="anApp" ng-controller="aCtrl">
    <select ng-change="RoomSelect()" ng-model="sRoom" ng-options="k.value as k.key for  k in chooses">
     </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="sRoom=1" name="cityID" id="Select1" ng-change="RoomSelect()" ng-model="sRoom">
                                            <option value="1" selected="selected">One</option>
                                            <option value="2">Two</option>
                                            <option value="3">Three</option>
                                            <option value="4">Four</option>
                                        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ng-init

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="sRoom=1"  name="cityID" id="Select1" ng-change="RoomSelect()"
```